# Why can't I set SOAP headers in pysimplesoap?

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl

I received some example php code for calling a SOAP service which I now need to convert to Python. In the php code they set the headers as follows:

```
$auth = array();
$auth['token'] = 'xxx';
if ($auth) {
    // add auth header
    $this->clients[$module]->__setSoapHeaders(
        new SoapHeader(
            $namespace, 
            'auth', 
            $auth
        )
    );
}
```

So the `auth` header should look like this: `['token' => 'xxx']`. I then loaded the wsdl into [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/), which gave me the following example xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sub="https://example.com/path/to/sub">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <sub:auth>
         <token>?</token>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <user_id>?</user_id>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <user_token>?</user_token>
      </sub:auth>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sub:customer_logos_pull>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <language>?</language>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <limit>?</limit>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <options_utc>?</options_utc>
      </sub:customer_logos_pull>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In pysimplesoap I now try something like this:

```
from pysimplesoap.client import SoapClient

WSDL = 'https://example.com/some/path/sub.wsdl'
TOKEN = 'xxx'

client = SoapClient(wsdl=WSDL, trace=True)
client['auth'] = {'token': TOKEN}
print client.customer_logos_pull({})
```

but I get an error saying `ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0`, which makes sense, because in the logged xml I see that the header is empty:

```
<soap:Header/>
```

I tried varying the code by including the `sub:` before `auth` like this: `client['sub:auth'] = {'token': TOKEN}`, but I get the same error.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Does it have to use [pysimplesoap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysimplesoap) -- It can't even be installed as it's kind of broken :/

Comment: @JamesMills - It doesn't need to be pysimplesoap per se. I just need to get it to work. I also tried it using suds. But I can't get that to work either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30874988/how-to-create-soap-header-with-python-suds-library  The library I use doesn't matter, it just needs to be in Python that's all. Would you know how to do it in a different library?

Answer (score 3):

So I think we can *solve* this by using the [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) library.

Here is a *very basic* example of how to send a SOAP request that includes headers:

**Example:**

```
from suds.sax.element import Element 

client = client(url) 
ssnns = ('ssn', 'http://namespaces/sessionid') 
ssn = Element('SessionID', ns=ssnns).setText('123') 
client.set_options(soapheaders=ssn)  
result = client.service.addPerson(person)
```

This is an example of how you'd send the following header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:SOAP ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
    <ssn:SessionID SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">123</ssn:SessionID>
 </SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

**NB:** I haven't actually *tried* this per se as I don't have access to any readily available SOAP/XML services I can test against!

So in your particular example you would do something like this:

```
>>> from suds.sax.element import Element
>>> subns = ("sub", "http://namespaces/sub")
>>> sub = Element("auth", ns=subns)
>>> token = Element("token").setText("?")
>>> user_id = Element("user_id").setText("?")
>>> user_token = Element("user_token").setText("?")
>>> sub.append(token)
Element (prefix=sub, name=auth)
>>> sub.append(user_id)
Element (prefix=sub, name=auth)
>>> sub.append(user_token)
Element (prefix=sub, name=auth)
>>> print(sub.str())
<sub:auth xmlns:sub="http://namespaces/sub">
   <token>?</token>
   <user_id>?</user_id>
   <user_token>?</user_token>
</sub:auth>
```

Then call `set_options()` on your `client` object:

```
client.set_options(soapheaders=sub)
```

---

And you can *easily* install [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) using [pip](https://pip.pypa.io) by running:

```
$ pip install suds
```