# How to create soap header with Python suds library?

Tags: python, soap, header, wsdl, suds

I need to call a SOAP service with a message like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sub="https://secure.xpslogic.com/service/wijnen/sub">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <sub:auth>
         <token>?</token>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <user_id>?</user_id>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <user_token>?</user_token>
      </sub:auth>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sub:customer_logos_pull>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <language>?</language>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <limit>?</limit>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <options_utc>?</options_utc>
      </sub:customer_logos_pull>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've got some php example code, which sets the headers as follows (and which works perfectly well):

auth = array();
$auth['token'] = 'xxx';
if ($auth) {
    // add auth header
    $this->clients[$module]->__setSoapHeaders(
        new SoapHeader(
            $namespace, 
            'auth', 
            $auth
        )
    );
}

I now construct the (empty) body and the header as follows with the [Python suds lib](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/):

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds import WebFault

client = Client(url='https://example.com/sub.wsdl')

auth = client.factory.create('auth')
auth.token = 'xxx'
client.set_options(soapheaders=auth)

customerLogosPull = client.factory.create('customer_logos_pull')
result = client.service.customer_logos_pull(customerLogosPull)
```

but this gives me a `not well-formed (invalid token)` message. When turning on logging I find this to be the message:

```
DEBUG:suds.mx.core:processing:
(Content){
   tag = "auth"
   value =
      (auth){
         token = "xxx"
         user_id = None
         user_token = None
      }
   type = <Element:0x10ff8c950 name="auth">
   <Complex:0x10ff8cbd0>
      <Sequence:0x10ff8cc50>
         <Element:0x10ff8cd10 name="token" type="(u'string', u'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')" />
         <Element:0x10ff8cd50 name="user_id" type="(u'string', u'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')" />
         <Element:0x10ff8cd90 name="user_token" type="(u'string', u'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')" />
      </Sequence>
   </Complex>
</Element>
 }
```

It looks pretty fine by me, but it also gives a `not well-formed (invalid token)`. seeing that the [suds docs has 3 examples](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#SOAPHEADERS) on how to pass in soap headers, I tried the other two as well:

```
>>> token = client.factory.create('auth.token')
>>> token.set(TOKEN)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: token instance has no attribute 'set'
```

and

```
>>> client.set_options(soapheaders={'auth': {'token': 'xxx'}})
>>> customerLogosPull = client.factory.create('customer_logos_pull')
>>> result = client.service.customer_logos_pull(customerLogosPull)
```

which gives this content in the logs, and still a `not well-formed (invalid token)`:

```
(Content){
   tag = "auth"
   value =
      {
         token = "xxx"
      }
   type = <Element:0x106049290 name="auth">
   <Complex:0x106049510>
      <Sequence:0x106049590>
         <Element:0x106049650 name="token" type="(u'string', u'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')" />
         <Element:0x106049690 name="user_id" type="(u'string', u'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')" />
         <Element:0x1060496d0 name="user_token" type="(u'string', u'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')" />
      </Sequence>
   </Complex>
</Element>
 }
```

Does anybody know how I can correctly set the token in the header using Python? All tips are welcome!

Comment: How did you get logging to format the logs for you?

Comment: if you need to set multiple soap headers, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61864899/4444742)

Answer (score 3):

I got my soap Headers working as below:

```
from suds.sax.element import Element
ssnp = Element("xsi:SessionHeader").append(Element('xsi:sessionId').setText("xxxxxxx"))
client.set_options(soapheaders=ssnp)
```

corresponding to soap Headers shown below in soap request xml

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <xsi:SessionHeader>
     <xsi:sessionId>xxxxxxx</xsi:sessionId>
  </xsi:SessionHeader>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

We can see what request was sent using `print client.last_sent()`

Answer (score 0):

I try with

```
from suds.client import Client
WSDL_URL='http://apitest.comune.genova.it:28280/MANU_WSManutenzioni_MOGE/'

#Create the Client:
print("Print 1")
client = Client(url=WSDL_URL)

print("Print 2")
from suds.sax.element import Element
ssnp = Element("xsi:SessionHeader").append(Element('xsi:Authorization').setText("XXXXXXXXXXX"))
client.set_options(soapheaders=ssnp)
```

but I encountered an error with the following line

```
client = Client(url=WSDL_URL)
```

Here the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 67, in open
    return self.u2open(u2request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 132, in u2open
    return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_ws.py", line 44, in <module>
    client = Client(url=WSDL_URL)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 115, in __init__
    self.wsdl = reader.open(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/suds/reader.py", line 151, in open
    d = self.fn(url, self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/suds/wsdl.py", line 136, in __init__
    d = reader.open(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/suds/reader.py", line 78, in open
    d = self.download(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/suds/reader.py", line 94, in download
    fp = self.options.transport.open(Request(url))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/suds/transport/https.py", line 62, in open
    return HttpTransport.open(self, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 69, in open
    raise TransportError(str(e), e.code, e.fp)
suds.transport.TransportError: HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed
```